How should I texture paint one area when faces on other parts of body share same texture?
How should I texture paint one area when faces on other parts of body share same texture?

Body texture painted with overlapping to other unintended areas

Use a Color > Mix Color to mix the 2 Image Texture nodes, the second Image Texture has a transparent background, use its Alpha output as factor:

